# C linked list why is my list head variable remaining null (new to C)

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

i received great help on my other questions in relation to this link list problem. My current problem is now that the head of the list remains null so i cannot actually link any nodes to it or print anything out to the console.

The problem is the insert_node function, so when print is called the while loop doesn't execute since head is null. I've got through it through the de bugger and it is definitely null it has the address 0x0.

Is this another malloc issue? im not too great on that yet.

code:

```
    /* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: che16
 *
 * Created on 20 November 2013, 08:59
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "structure.h"

/*
 * 
 */

node* head = NULL;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int no;

    printf("enter amount of books \n");

    scanf("%d", &no);

    create_books(no);
    print_list(head);


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}

node* create_books(int no_of_books) {
    char title[50];
    char author[30];
    unsigned int number;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < no_of_books; i++) {
        node* new_node;
        new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof (node));
        printf("enter book title \n");
        scanf("%s", title);
        printf("enter author name \n");
        scanf("%s", author);
        printf("enter ISDN number \n");
        scanf("%10u", &number);

        strncpy(new_node->btitle, title, 40);
        strncpy(new_node->name, author, 40);

        new_node->isbn = number;
        new_node->n = NULL;


        insert_node(head, new_node);
    }
}

void insert_node(node* head, node* insert) {
    printf("insert called \n");
    insert->n = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = insert;
    } else {
        node* curr = head;

        while (curr->n != NULL) {
            curr = curr->n;
        }
        curr->n = insert;
    }
    printf("finished called \n");

}

void delete_node(node* head, node * node) {

}

void print_list(node * head) {
    while (head) {
        printf("%s: \"%s\" (%u)\n", head->btitle, head->name, head->isbn);

        head = head->n;
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: che16
 *
 * Created on 20 November 2013, 08:59
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "structure.h"

/*
 * 
 */

node** head = NULL;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int no;

    printf("enter amount of books \n");

    scanf("%d", &no);

    create_books(no);
    print_list(head);


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}

node* create_books(int no_of_books) {
    char title[50];
    char author[30];
    unsigned int number;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < no_of_books; i++) {
        node* new_node;
        new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof (node));
        printf("enter book title \n");
        scanf("%s", title);
        printf("enter author name \n");
        scanf("%s", author);
        printf("enter ISDN number \n");
        scanf("%10u", &number);

        strncpy(new_node->btitle, title, 40);
        strncpy(new_node->name, author, 40);

        new_node->isbn = number;
        new_node->n = NULL;


        insert_node(&head, new_node);
    }
}

void insert_node(node** head, node* insert) {
    printf("insert called \n");
    insert->n = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = insert;
    } else {
        node* curr = *head;

        while (curr->n != NULL) {
            curr = curr->n;
        }
        curr->n = insert;
    }
    printf("finished called \n");

}

void delete_node(node* head, node * node) {

}

void print_list(node * head) {
    while (head) {
        printf("%s: \"%s\" (%u)\n", head->btitle, head->name, head->isbn);

        head = head->n;
    }
}
```

Comment: (guesses without looking at code at all:) because you modify a local variable that you should be passing around by-pointer instead?

Comment: (looks at code. realizes being right. bangs head into nearby wall.)

Comment: whats in structure.h? what does create_books and print_list do?

Comment: @TamásZahola irrelevant (look at `insert_node()`...)

Comment: @H2CO3 Seems like it's the season for "no idea about pass by value/reference"...

Comment: @John3136 and it's a very long season!

Comment: @H2CO3 if he is setting `head` as a global variable, then does he even need to pass it to the function?

Comment: @metsales no, but passing function arguments is better practice than using globals.

Comment: @H2CO3 this is very true. What about using a `.h` file with global variables or is it the same thing just different way of doing it?

Comment: @metsales even worse. will get additional linker errors.

Comment: @H2CO3 always wondered about that. 2 things I never used in C are global variables and magic numbers, because with globals they are tough to control. As for magic numbers... I think its just good practice.

Comment: @metsales You're my hero.

Comment: im probably doing this in a really bad way, but it's a "do it yourself" task you just get given an a4 sheets of paper with the words "make a link list that is sorted based on book ISBN" i will sort once i can get a normal list working but this a huge step up from out previous work which was basically typedef and print out the  variables not gonna lie im out of my depth!

Comment: @chrisedwards you should look into sorting as you add things to your linked list. Don't even look at a computer, think about it logically for a minute, draw a diagram or something. have a `temp` pointer and a `head` pointer. The `temp` pointer will be what you use to search through the list, and the `head` will always be pointing to the start of your list. So you insert a node and then have an `if` statement that determines where to put the node. So `if ( isbn < node.isbn ) then`... move to the next node and test again.

Comment: @metsales sorting is now added as i insert :) learnt a lot C tonight **  pointers massively helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing `head` as a local variable into the `insert_node` function, rather than using the global one.

You have three options here:

1. Make all your functions act on the global `head` and not pass it around (not recommended);
2. Pass `head` as a `node**`, so that functions can change the `node*` value it points to;
3. Use a *dummy head* strategy where the head is an empty list node that is never NULL, and never changes.  You use its `next` pointer as the actual list head.  This approach tends to make all your list code much simpler at the expense of a little wasted memory.

Comment: never thought about #3 but seems the most elegant solution to me so you get a +0.9999999999999999999999 that rounds up to 1.

Comment: @paddy the worksheets doesn't allow dummy heads for the first part there is a later part that does. im not sure how to implement the ** we have not been shown that is there an example at all? sorry im bad at C but im trying! i tried setting insert_node to insert_node(node** node, node* node) but that didnt work

Comment: sorted i was missing an & when passing head, ill update original and thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This is because of your `insert_node` function, where you set the *local* variable `head = insert;`. The global head variable remains untouched. You should change your function as follows: `insert_node(node*& head, node* insert)`. With that, you pass a *reference* to the global head.

**Edit**: yes, sorry, in C there are no references. So see answer #2 from paddy...

Comment: There's no reference type in C.

Comment: Wouldn't `node*& head` be the same thing as `node head`?

Comment: @metsales no, that's not the address-of operator, that's the reference qualifier from C++, and it doesn't work in C.