# head is always null in linked list insert

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to insert into my linked list. Here is what I wrote for the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};


void show_menu()
{
    printf("\nWhat do you want to do: \n");
    printf("1.Insert \n2.Delete \n3.Show"); 
    printf("\nEnter your choice: \n");
}

void insert(struct node *head)
{
    int new_numer;
    printf("Enter a number to insert in the linked list: \n");
    scanf("%d",&new_numer);

    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head->data = new_numer;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *temp = head;

        struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        new_node -> data = new_numer;

        new_node -> next = NULL;

        while( temp -> next != NULL )
        {
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
        temp->next = new_node;
    }
}


void show(struct node *head)
{
    printf("\n The elements in the list are: \n");
    while ( head != NULL )
    {
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head -> next;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int choice;

    struct node *head = NULL;


    while(1)
    {
        show_menu();
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                insert(head);
                show(head);
            break;

            case 2:
                show(head);
            break;

            case 3:
            break;

            default:
                printf("Don't fuck with me.\n");
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

On running the code, I got:

```
What do you want to do: 
1.Insert 
2.Delete 
3.Show
Enter your choice: 
1
Enter a number to insert in the linked list: 
12

 The elements in the list are: 

What do you want to do: 
1.Insert 
2.Delete 
3.Show
Enter your choice:
```

Why there is no element inserted in the list?

If I am moving

```
head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

to the main function, I am getting first element as zero and other inserted.

What am I missing here?

Comment: don't you want to attach the new_node you allocated to head?

Comment: `insert()` can't modify the `head` from `main()`, since it's passed by value.  You need to pass a pointer to it for that (ie. a pointer to pointer to struct node)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C linked list why is my list head variable remaining null (new to C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108412/c-linked-list-why-is-my-list-head-variable-remaining-null-new-to-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that when you are inserting the first element, the head isn't changing. You have passed its values to the function.

What you need to do is pass the address of head i.e. `struct node** head` and then modify `*head` if it is the first element being inserted.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: So, you have set head to NULL in the main. And you are passing it to insert function. You are passing a copy of head. So the head inside the function is NULL. Now you change it in the if condition. The local copy of head has changed but the head in main is still the same. For it, no insertion has actually happened.

Comment: Yes, it is pointer to a struct. But it is still a variable. To change the contents of the variable in the insert function you will need a pointer to the pointer. Hence the `struct node **head`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Any tutorial for the same. It's quite confusing, felt like inception. :)

Comment: Yes, you can have any depth for a pointer. For further explanation you might want to see the comment JohnnyMopp made.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to change the value of some variable passed to a function, you need to pass by reference or use pointer of the variable. Same is the case here. The function `insert` changes the value of your variable `head`, which is a pointer. So you will have to pass a pointer of the pointer.

Thus, the argument has to be  `struct node **head` and in the `main()` function pass `&head` to `insert()`.