# why do we need to return head in a function which inserts a node at the end of a linked list and why not in the case of arrays for similar operation

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

to insert a new node in a linked list at the end we have the following code in main() function :

```
struct node *newNode;
newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newNode->data = 4;
newNode->next = NULL;

struct node *temp = head;
while(temp->next != NULL){
  temp = temp->next;
}

temp->next = newNode;
```

to make this as a function we have following code :

```
struct node *insertAtEnd(struct node *head, int data)
{
    struct node *ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->data = data;
    struct node *p = head;

    while (p->next != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = ptr;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *first;
    struct node *second;
    struct node *third;

    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    first = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // fill data in head and point it to next node
    head->data = 69;
    head->next = first;

    // fill data in first and point it to next node
    first->data = 54;
    first->next = second;

    // fill data in second and point it to next node
    second->data = 33;
    second->next = third;

    // fill data in third and point it to null
    third->data = 36;
    third->next = NULL;
    printf("linked list before traversal : ");
    linkedListTraversal(head);
    printf("\n\nlinked list after traversal : ");

    head = insertAtEnd(head, 88);

    // a function to print all the data in linked list
    linkedListTraversal(head);
    return 0;
}
```

why do we have to return the value of head and store it again into the same head declared in main even if it's value isn't changing and, as far as my knowledge of c language is concerned, has nothing to do with changes happening to it's leading nodes as it only has information of it's next node.

what think about this doubt is  this :

We are using pointer because we want to make some permanent changes in the link  list data structure so we need to pass by value.In case of link list we are returning         the pointer and storing it in the head node, but in case of array we didn't have to         return anything it is because, in case of array we were just tampering with the data         which is stored inside the array indices but in case of linked list we are tampering         with their addresses, changing their values. So either we need to return the pointer         and store it into the head node(which is again a pointer) or we need to use the double         pointer, In that case we can implement these function with void return type. In other         words with don't need to return anything.Double pointer means a pointer variable which         can store the address of the address of a specific data type.

Comment: There are two common methods of dealing with a linked list. Pick whichever one you want. (OT: 1) don't cast the return value from `malloc()`. 2) verify that the return value is not NULL, 3) use `typedef` to reduce the verbosity of this code, 4) use `free()` to relinquish memory to avoid memory leaks.)

Comment: Short answer: So you can return the new head when you insert into an empty list. Unfortunately, your code does not handle that situation.

Comment: The names of your pointers in the function `main` are a bit misleading. The `head` pointer points to the first node, but you are making the pointer `first` instead point to the second node.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [head is always null in linked list insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102026/head-is-always-null-in-linked-list-insert)

Answer (score 2):

Your posted code is incorrect. The code

```
struct node *p = head;

while (p->next != NULL)
{
    p = p->next;
}
```

in the function `insertAtEnd` will crash if `head == NULL` (i.e. if the list is empty), because you are not allowed to dereference `p` when it is `NULL`.

I suggest that you instead write the function `insertAtEnd` like this:

```
struct node *insertAtEnd( struct node *head, int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof *new_node );
    if ( new_node == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        return new_node;
    }

    struct node *p = head;

    while ( p->next != NULL )
    {
        p = p->next;
    }

    p->next = new_node;

    return head;
}
```

Now if the function `insertAtEnd` is called when the list is empty, your function will no longer crash, but will instead return the address of the new head. Therefore, it is now important that the function `main` uses this return value by overwriting the old head pointer with the address of the new head.

However, personally, I prefer not to make the function `insertAtEnd` return the address of the new head. Instead, I prefer to pass a pointer to the pointer `head` in `main` to the function `insertAtEnd`, so that the function `insertAtEnd` can itself modify the pointer `head` in the function `main` via the pointer:

```
void insertAtEnd( struct node **pp_head, int data )
{
    struct node **pp_next = pp_head;

    //make pp_next point to the NULL pointer at the end of the list, or
    //to the head pointer in "main" if the list is empty
    while ( *pp_next != NULL )
    {
        pp_next = &(*pp_next)->next;
    }

    //allocate and initialize new node
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof *new_node );
    if ( new_node == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    //link new node with the end of the list, or make it the new head if
    //the list was empty
    *pp_next = new_node;
}
```

Here is a full code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void insertAtEnd( struct node **pp_head, int data )
{
    struct node **pp_next = pp_head;

    //make pp_next point to the NULL pointer at the end of the list, or
    //to the head pointer in "main" if the list is empty
    while ( *pp_next != NULL )
    {
        pp_next = &(*pp_next)->next;
    }

    //allocate and initialize new node
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof *new_node );
    if ( new_node == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    //link new node with the end of the list, or make it the new head if
    //the list was empty
    *pp_next = new_node;
}

void print_list( struct node *head )
{
    for ( struct node *p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", p->data );
    }
}

void free_list( struct node *head )
{
    for ( struct node *p = head; p != NULL;  )
    {
        struct node *temp = p;
        p = p->next;
        free( temp );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    //add nodes to the initially empty list, one node
    //at a time
    insertAtEnd( &head, 69 );
    insertAtEnd( &head, 54 );
    insertAtEnd( &head, 33 );
    insertAtEnd( &head, 36 );
    insertAtEnd( &head, 88 );

    //print content of linked list
    printf( "The linked list has the following content:\n");
    print_list( head );

    //free all nodes in the list
    free_list( head );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
The linked list has the following content:
69
54
33
36
88
```

As you can see, all five nodes were successfully added to the initially empty linked list, and the program now does not crash when calling `insertAtEnd` when `head == NULL` (i.e. when the list is empty).

I added some code to check the return value of `malloc`, because otherwise, the code will crash if `malloc` ever returns `NULL` (which may happen if there is for example insufficient memory).

Also, I added code for freeing all nodes, to prevent a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: I'm looking at this implementation of insertAtEnd(), and I'm thinking, that's going to keep changing the head to the newly added node, thereby losing the head of the linked list. *pp_head should be assigned to point to the new none only if *pp_head == null.

Comment: @RobH: Actually, the name of the variable `pp_head` was misleading, because only at the start of the function `insertAtEnd` was it guaranteed to be pointing to the pointer to the head node. If the list was not empty, then I made `pp_head` point to the NULL pointer at the end of the list (i.e. which is the `next` member of the last node), which makes the name misleading. In order to prevent the use of this misleading name, I have now edited my code to use the variable `pp_head` only as a function parameter. I am now using the new variable `pp_next` for what `pp_head` was previously used.

Comment: @RobH: This code change does not change the behavior of the program, but it should now be clearer what the variable does. The variable `pp_next` will point to the `NULL` pointer at the end of the list (which is the `next` member of the last node), or if the list is empty, it will point to the pointer `head` in the function `main`. That way, the address of the new node should always be written to `*pp_next`, whether the list is empty or not. Therefore, the function no longer has to distinguish between the cases of the list being empty and the list being not empty, which makes it simpler.

Comment: There's still the issue of when the head pointer gets set when the first node is added. I don't see any code that does that; and if that never gets set, then the head pointer always ends up being null. (That's the whole point of passing a pointer to head into `insertAtEnd()`.)

Comment: @RobH: If the final version of my function `insertAtEnd` is called when the list is empty, then the `pp_head` parameter will point to the pointer `head` of the function `main`, which has the value `NULL`.  The value of `pp_head` will be copied to `pp_next`, so that it will now also point to `head`. It won't be modified further if the list is empty, so the line `*pp_next = new_node;` will set `head` to the value of `new_node`. Therefore, your statement that `head` will remain `NULL` is incorrect. You may want to test the final version of my posted code. As you can see by the output, it works.

Comment: I prefer the version which returns the new head, but the other works too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Linus Torvalds (the creator of the Linux kernel) [has a pretty strong opinion on which one is better](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/). ;-)

Answer (score -1):

In reviewing your initial code, I actually did not see a need for returning the head node pointer back in the function call.  Rather, I did a bit of refactoring making the function a "void" function instead.  Following is a refactored version of your code changing the insert function to be a "void return" function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Educated guess of the node structure

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
};

// Functional traversal and print function

void linkedListTraversal(struct node * head)
{
    struct node * work = head;

    while (work != NULL)
    {
        printf("Data: %d\n", work->data);
        work = work->next;
    }

    return;
}

void insertAtEnd(struct node *head, int data)
{
    struct node *ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->data = data;
    struct node *p = head;

    while (p->next != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = ptr;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    struct node *head;

    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // Set up initial node data in head

    head->data = 69;
    head->next = NULL;

    // Fill data into first new node after the head node

    insertAtEnd(head, 54);

    // Fill data in second new node after the head node

    insertAtEnd(head, 33);

    // Fill data in third new node after the head node

    insertAtEnd(head, 36);

    printf("linked list before traversal : ");
    linkedListTraversal(head);
    printf("\n\nlinked list after traversal : ");

    // Create one more node

    insertAtEnd(head, 88);

    // A function to print all the data in linked list
    linkedListTraversal(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Utilizing the function in that manner actually made the creation of the subsequent nodes associated to the head node structure simpler.  Instead of repeatedly declaring a node structure and then manually linking the structure, I just utilized the refactored function to create all subsequent structures.

With that here was the terminal output from running a test of the refactored code.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/NodeList/bin/Release$ ./NodeList 
linked list before traversal : Data: 69
Data: 54
Data: 33
Data: 36


linked list after traversal : Data: 69
Data: 54
Data: 33
Data: 36
Data: 88
```

Possibly I have missed some element of the issue, but if not, this refactored function should satisfy the requirements of creating and linking node structures to the head structure and provide the necessary link structure list.

Give this a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: The function `insertAtEnd` will crash when `head == NULL` (i.e. when the list is empty). OP's code also has this problem. If it is guaranteed that the function `insertAtEnd` will never be used on an empty list, then you are correct that you don't need a return value, because the head will never be changed by the insertion. However, I do not think that it is appropriate to assume that the function `insertAtEnd` will never be called on an empty list, even if this is the case in OP's code.

Comment: Yes.  You make a good point about utilizing this function with an empty list.  I was focusing in on the context of this program where an initial structure is created, so that's good that you pointed out that caveat.